# Looking for an algorithm that splits shifts by breaks

Tags: python, list

I have a list of shifts that are defined by start time and end time in integers, e.g.

```
shifts = [[0,10], [12,18], [22,37]]
```

Also I have a list of breaks that are defined in the same way:

```
breaks = [[2,3], [5,8], [22,25]]
```

I am looking for an algorithm that splits shifts where breaks occur:

```
def split_shifts(shifts, breaks):
    # missing code
```

such that for the example above the function returns

```
split_shifts(shifts, breaks)
> [[0,2],[3,5],[8,10],[12,18],[25,37]]
```

My approach is

```
new_shifts = []
for pause in breaks:
    for shift in shifts:
        if time_overlap(shift, pause):
            new_shifts.extend(split_shift(shift, pause))
            break
```

but the result is wrong where several breaks overlap the same shift.

How would you solve this problem? It looks like I need to loop over `new_shifts` while changing the elements of `new_shifts`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can flatten, concatenate, and sort the two nested lists, then pair the elements two by two as they come, while eliminating pairs of identical elements.

```
flat = sorted(sum(shifts, []) + sum(breaks, []))
[[flat[idx], flat[idx+1]] for idx in range(0, len(flat)-1, 2) if flat[idx] != flat[idx+1]]
```

#### output:

```
[[0, 2], [3, 5], [8, 10], [12, 18], [25, 37]]
```

Comment: First of all: wow! It works in all cases I have tested but I am not sure how it works. Why does the step size have to be 2? Or more precisely why does it not ouput `[2,3]`?

Comment: Cool, I am pleased it works for you, and you like it. The step size is 2 in order to pair the values without repeating the last one; if the step size is one, a sequence like `[1, 2, 3, 4]` would output `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]` instead of `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`

Comment: I think a pretty deep observation that you exploit in your algorithm is that active and inactive intervals are strictly alternating if all breaks are within shifts. Hence every other pair of your flattened list is an active part of a shift. Amazingly this is consistent with gaps between shifts which might as well be modeled as breaks of the "super shift" that starts at the beginning of the first shift and ends at the end of the last shift.

Comment: This also explains how your algorithm "knows" that `[2,3]` is not an active interval

Answer (score 2):

Pierre's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59334239/3051715) works, but goes over the shift list multiple time, which might not be necessary.

Assuming the shifts and breaks are ordered, and have no overlapping between two shifts or two breaks, you can achieve it by going over each list only one.

The essence is to "consume" the breaks by order for each shift, and for each `split_shift`, split the shift only to two:

```
def split_single_shift(shift, break):
    return (shift[0], break[0]), (break[1], shift[1])

def split_shifts(shifts, breaks):
    next_break_index = 0
    new_shifts = []
    for shift in shifts:
        while next_break_index < len(breaks) \
              and time_overlap(shift, breaks[next_break_index]):
            prev_shift, shift = split_single_shift(shift, breaks[next_break_index])
            new_shifts.append(prev_shift)
            next_break_index+=1
    return new_shifts
```

Note that if a break is completely aligned with a shift, you'll need to add a special check to ensure you don't get "empty shift" like `(10,10)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to do it break by break, to update the shifts one break at a time:

```
def split_shifts(shifts, breaks):
    splitted_shifts = shifts.copy()
    for b in breaks:
        splitted_shifts = split_shifts_for_break(splitted_shifts, b)
    return splitted_shifts



def split_shifts_for_break(shifts, single_break):
    splitted_shifts = []
    for s in shifts:
        if single_break[0] > s[0] and single_break[1] < s[1]:
            splitted_shifts += [[s[0], single_break[0]], [single_break[1], s[1]]]
        else:
            splitted_shifts += [s]
    return splitted_shifts
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use numpy library to get the desired output.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

nw = sorted((shifts + breaks),key=lambda x: x[0]) # sort by 1st element
# output: [[0, 10], [2, 3], [5, 8], [12, 18], [22, 37], [22, 25]]

sb = np.array(sorted(list(chain.from_iterable(nw))))
# output: #[ 0  2  3  5  8 10 12 18 22 22 25 37]
```

Notice that 22 22 will produce [22 22] and it doesn't make sense: starting point and ending point are the same

```
 repeated = [r for n, r in enumerate(sb) if r in sb[:n]] # output: [22]
 sb = sb[sb != repeated]

 range_list = []
 for i in range(len(sb)):

      if i%2 == 0 or i == 0 : # skip [2 3],[5 8],etc...

          range_list.append(sb[i:i+2])

 print(range_list)
 #[array([0, 2]), array([3, 5]), array([ 8, 10]), array([12, 18]), array([25, 37])]
```

Comment: You explicitly require that the first interval is an active interval in your append condition (`or i == 0`).You algorithm gets it wrong for `shifts=[[0,10]]` and `breaks=[[0,3]]`. @Reblochons algorithms detects which intervals to skip by the repeated indices!

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will review my code and try to find a solution. Reblochons’ code is a great one, upvoted it myself, before posting mine. I was looking for a solution with numpy.